# call to jquery ajax failing with 500 error when passing extra data field

Tags: posts, ajax, 500-internal-error

I have the following jQuery for doing an Ajax call and it works fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
$( "#mystatus" ).change(runMyStatus);

 function runMyStatus() {
  var mystatus = this.value;
  var data = {
        'action': 'bikeride_mystatus_function',
        'mystatus': mystatus,
        // 'rideID' : 123,
        'nonce': frontEndAjax.nonce
    };

   var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
       url: frontEndAjax.ajaxurl,
       type: "post",
       data: data
   });
   ajaxRequest.done(function(response) {
     alert('Success');
   });
   ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, exception) {
     alert('Error.\n' + jqXHR.status + ' ::' + textStatus + ' ::' + exception);
   });
 } // end runMyStatus
// end document ready
});
```

If I uncomment the line with rideID then it fails with a "500" status (I tried putting 123 in quotes but it made no difference). If I change the type from "post" to "get" then it works. This error occurs even with no plugins enabled and using the twentyseventeen theme. Any idea what is causing the error?

Comment: I think the issue is caused by or lies within your server-side AJAX handler/function. You should check its code and confirm whether the request method should be `GET` or `POST` (it's the `type` property used in the `data` object for your `$.ajax()` call).

Comment: `500` is an Internal Server Error, so would be caused by the PHP function used to handle the request. Can you include this in your question.

Comment: Try replacing type: "post" with method: 'POST'

Comment: Hi Jacob, You're correct the 500 indicates something in the PHP function failed. If I comment out some of the code in the php function then it works. I just need to fix the php code. Thanks!